# No module named SkyNet found - problem installing open source code

Tags: python, ubuntu, package

SkyNet is publicly available as an open-source software at https://bitbucket.org/jlippuner/skynet. I am having problems installing this software. I am using Ubuntu, and I have downloaded all needed packages using apt. All tests pass (not at first, but after restarting), but the problems start when I try to run the example code.

As instructed at the bitbucket page, I have used CMake to try to install the package, and all files seem to be installed, and the tests work.

The first line in the code is `from SkyNet import *`, but this just returns `No module named 'Skynet' found`. I have tried to reinstall and using different versions of Python, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That error seems strange, is it correct? The two module names differ by case.

Comment: @Sasszem oh yeah, I just typed it wrong in the question xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the [Skynet documentation install page](https://bitbucket.org/jlippuner/skynet/src/49ff6c91d58d7bcc97143b649329ed186b0958ae/INSTALL#lines-138:%7E:text=137-,138,-139) I found this,

For python to find the Skynet module the directory in which it exists has to be added to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Replace `install_dir` with directory where the Skynet module has been installed to.

```
echo "export PYTHONPATH=<install_dir>/lib:\$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bashrc
```

An alternative approach would be to add the path where Skynet module exists to `sys.path` at the top of your script file.

Example

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/Skynet")
from Skynet import *
```

[Here is a link to](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#path-entry-finders) documentation on how python resolves module imports

Answer (score 0):

It may come from the old python2.7.
I used `pip install skynet` to install the module.
Then I changed python code.

```
from Skynet import *
```

to

```
from skynet import *
```